# Call Widget from phtml file?

Tags: magento2, widgets

Trying to call a widget (from a custom form extension) in a phtml.

Here's what it looks like when embedded in a CMS page:

`{widget type="PluginCompany\ContactForms\Block\Form\Widget\View" form_id="1" show_form_as="form"}`

How would I print this in a phtml file, and in such a way that passes those parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must define this class into your block

```
PluginCompany\ContactForms\Block\Form\Widget\View
```

So that you can call it from your template.

Then create a function like:

```
public function getWidgetBlock() {
    return $this->widgetBlock;
}
```

Where **`$this->widgetBlock`** is the variable which will set for widget class in constructor.

Then call this function in `phtml`, then set those variables like: **`setFormId(1);`** and **`setShowFormAs('form');`**

After setting these variables you can get widget output by calling function **`toHtml()`** from this variable.

For Eg:

```
$widget = $block->getWidgetBlock(); 
$widget->setFormId(1)->setShowFormAs('form')->toHtml();
```